# Grinding noise coming out of PC

Tags: desktop-computer

A weird grinding noise is coming out from my PC in a breathing pattern. The grinding starts low and then go ups and then back down. This all happens in around 5 seconds. Normally this happens 3-4 times and then it stops. It comes back quite frequently. I can't pinpoint exactly what makes it happen as it does happen when my computer is just on but it does happen more frequently when under some load.

Comment: If you take the case off, are you able to find the area that it's coming from? It sounds like it may be a fan (perhaps the GPU fan) which is wearing out or rubbing against something.

Comment: I will have a check in the morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the noise of a failing fan.

There are fans in multiple places of your computer. Possibly:

1. The case / side covers
2. The video card
3. The CPU
4. The power supply

It will involve running the computer with the cover removed. If you cannot pinpoint the sound, then physically find and inspect each fan to make sure it is spinning. If it is spinning, you can use a plastic instrument to stop the movement of the fan and then release it. You should be able to find the fan that is making noise or not spinning properly.

The next step is to replace the fan or the unit containing the fan, if it is something like a power supply.

Comment: You can rule out Power Supply,Video card and CPU. I changed them recently and that didn't stop it. So it has to be the case/side covers. I will test them out tomorrow and get back to you

Comment: Ok Seems like its the GPU. I'm returning it. Thanks for the help